# Построить регулярное выражение

Tags: регулярные-выражения, лексический-анализатор

Мне нужно построить регулярное выражение для строк в которых символы +/- не могут стоять рядом (обязаны быть разделены каким-то другим). У меня получился вот такой вариант: `(a*(+|-)a)*` , где `a` - любой символ, `*` - замыкание Клини, `()` - для наглядности. Но данная строка не распознает строки вида: "+", "-","+a-" и т.д. Может кто-то сможет сдвинуть меня с мертвой точки. Регулярка мне необходима для построения конечного автомата.

Comment: По-моему проще проверить, что 2 символа рядом `[+-]{2,}` и написать `if not`. Ну или через negative match того же выражения `^((?![+-]{2,}).)*$`

Comment: @GrAnd, у меня нет операции отрицания и повторения m раз. Только конкатенация, замыкания Клини и объединение(т.е. ab - конкатенация, * - клини, | - объединение)